# Simple expense/income tracking Android app

Tags: android, finance

I want to know if such an app is already available on Play store or somewhere else for Android.

[image]

I have tried a few but they are really bloated with unnecessary options.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to list in text form which features the app needs to have / how the workflows should be? Not every reader is able to perceive images.

Comment: it would also help, if you can list which you have tried and why they don't fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Mint](https://www.mint.com/)?:

> Effortlessly stay on top of bills
>
> At last, your bills and money are together in one place and easier than ever to manage.
> Just add your bills to see how helpful we can be.
> See bills and money in one place.
> Get alerts and schedule payments on the spot.
> Say goodbye to late fees.
> Stop logging into multiple sites.
> Deliver payments fast.

Comment: Not as simple as the concept above

Answer (score 0):

What about [Spendee](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleevio.spendee&hl=en)? It is as simple as you describe and contains a lot of the features that you want like

- The main screen from which you can add transactions
- Screen that sums the transactions per type.